# Как отобразить gif на форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку запускается длительная операция. Хотелось бы вместо привычного progressbar заюзать небольшую gif-ку.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Не знаете как гиф отобразить на форме?

Comment: gif можно открыть в PictureBox, а пример вывода анимированного gif [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485477/can-a-picturebox-show-animated-gif-in-windows-application)

Answer (score 1):

Так как вопрос сформулирован не точно, отвечу с точки зрения взаимодействия с пользователем (Human–computer interaction).

Я бы Вам посоветовал:

- Оставить и прогресс выполнения операции (Progress Bar)
- Добавить анимацию выполнения процесса (анимация хороша тем, что всё время находится в движении, в отличии от Progress Bar, хотя начиная с Windows Vista он постоянно переливается)
- Добавить сколько примерно времени осталось ждать

  Хорошим примером является диалоговое окно копирования в MS Windows.

[image]

Более подробно описано в книге Алана Купера ["Об интерфейсе. Основы проектирования взаимодействия"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4562908/) страница 580, глава "Диалоговые окна процессов".